# scope of this, need help understanding a part of todoMVC app

Tags: javascript

I have some trouble reading one part of the basic todoMVC build with vanillaJS:
https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/vanillajs/js

So in view.js, we see

```
View.prototype.bind = function (event, handler) {
    var self = this;
    [...]
    } else if (event === 'itemToggle') {
        $delegate(self.$todoList, '.toggle', 'click', function () {
            handler({
                id: self._itemId(this),
                completed: this.checked
            });
        });
```

Now `this`.check, Im not entirely sure which scope `this` will be refer to when the program actually get run. Would it simply be the DOM object that got clicked on? since it will be the one that running the handler function??

Under controller we have

```
function Controller(model, view) {
    var self = this;
    self.model = model;
    self.view = view;
    [...]
    self.view.bind('itemToggle', function (item) {
        self.toggleComplete(item.id, item.completed);
    });
 }

  Controller.prototype.toggleComplete = function (id, completed, silent) {
    var self = this;
    self.model.update(id, { completed: completed }, function () {
        self.view.render('elementComplete', {
            id: id,
            completed: completed
        });
    });

    if (!silent) {
        self._filter();
    }
};
```

Comment: The scope of *this* is only ever the current execution context. In arrow functions, *this* is set to the outer execution context's *this*. How *this* is set in the first place depends on how the function was called, or use of *Function.prototype.bind*.

Comment: While I know the definition, in here there are quite a few callback nesting Im having trouble with this. So was I right about `Would it simply be the DOM object that got clicked on?`

Comment: For a *view* instance, where it has `var self = this` then *this* (and hence *self*) should reference the view (noting that *this* may be set to some other value in the call).  Within `handler(...)` *this* should be the DOM element whose handler called the listener (again with the former caveat that *this* can be set to anything by the call or with *bind*). So the simple answer is "yes".

Comment: perfect, thank you so much for clearing that up!